# Initiate/bind views before its visible for the first time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So I have this ViewPager that contains quite many pages with Fragments(15) and inside those fragments there are quite a lot of small ImageViews. These takes some time to bind initially, which I would prefer that the user would not have to wait for. The ViewPager is View.GONE at first when one enters the activity. You have to first push a button for it to appear for the first time.

What I want to do is to bind the views with (findViewById etc.) before the views containing the ViewPager actually becomes visible for the first time, so that when the user presses the Button to make it appear, it happens instantly. Now it takes some time the first time I press the appear-Button, but the second, third etc it happens instantly. 
When I enter the activity, I do initiate the views and set adapter to the ViewPager and the view containing it, in the "onCreate" method, but still it seems like it does it again the first time the View containing the ViewPager appear(become Visible) for the first time. 
Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) as your `ViewPager` adapter. This way, your fragments will be loaded and destroyed as needed, ahead of time, but not all at the once when you first load your `Activity` or `Fragment` containing the view pager.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! It certainly did help, but did not solve it totally.

Comment: It takes less time now for sure, but it still not pre loaded before first visible state. But it really did help so thanks!